# How to add a video having full width and also adjustable height to the website

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to add a video to the website using video from local machine. If I use the html5 video source property when I adjust the height it affect the width but I need full width video.

Comment: where is your code

Comment: Could you just turn up the brightness on your screen? It's a little hard to see the code you've *already tried*...

Comment: What about aspect ration then?

Comment: Then use width:100% on that video.

Comment: Rex, please include the HTML code and CSS if possible of the example you're using. As it is, your question is not allowed to be posted.